# Cross compile with gcc on linux ubuntu 16.04 LTS error

Tags: c, gcc, jenkins, cross-compiling, sdl-2

I have recently installed a Jenkins server on my Ubuntu server. I've been trying to compile several types builds (for linux distro, for windows and an intel-asm generator). Linux and asm builds work fine and compile without errors the problem comes with the `gcc-mingw32` compiler.

It's also important to state that I am using `SDL2`, `SDL_image` and `SDL_mixer` librabies to compile the code.

**When I run the build for i686 jenkins logs me this:**

```
 23:32:38 /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lSDL2_image
 23:32:38 /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lSDL2_mixer
 23:32:38 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**My shell command is written like this:**

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o lastBuild.exe main.c engine.c -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer
```

Both the `SDL_image` and `SDL_mixer` are present in the `/usr/lib` under the sub-directory `/x86_64-linux-gnu`

**Here is the code from my server confirming the library instalation:**

```
sudo dpkg -L libsdl2-image-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/examples
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/examples/showimage.c
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/copyright
/usr/include
/usr/include/SDL2
/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/SDL2_image.pc
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so
```

I tried to put these libraries somewhere else and link them but it didn't seem to work. Also the `SDL2` linking seems to be working fine (it's under `/usr/lib` as well).

Comment: You have to distinguish **host** libraries from **target** ones. You showed **host** when you actually need **target**.

Comment: @0andriy Oh right so i was acctually using linux sdl libs to compile in i686 from the dev package? But why is `SDL2` not giving me an error by itself only it's libraries?

Comment: @Primemaster I fail to see how you expect "SDL2 to give you an error". Cross compiler requires libraries for its target platform and fails to find it. You can either build these libraries or download them from e.g. libsdl.org and tell linker where to find them (`-L`).